# Hazelcast not shutting down gracefully in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, hazelcast, spring-cache

I'm trying to understand how Spring Boot shut down distributed Hazelcast cache. When I connect and then shut down a second instance I get the following logs:

##### First Instance (Still Running)

```
2021-09-20 15:34:47.994  INFO 11492 --- [.IO.thread-in-0] c.h.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnection     : [localhost]:8084 [dev] [4.0.2] Initialized new cluster connection between /127.0.0.1:8084 and /127.0.0.1:60552
2021-09-20 15:34:54.048  INFO 11492 --- [ration.thread-0] c.h.internal.cluster.ClusterService      : [localhost]:8084 [dev] [4.0.2] 

Members {size:2, ver:2} [
    Member [localhost]:8084 - 4c874ad9-04d1-4857-8279-f3a47be3070b this
    Member [localhost]:8085 - 2282b4e7-2b6d-4e5b-9ac8-dfac988ce39f
]

2021-09-20 15:35:11.087  INFO 11492 --- [.IO.thread-in-0] c.h.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnection     : [localhost]:8084 [dev] [4.0.2] Connection[id=1, /127.0.0.1:8084->/127.0.0.1:60552, qualifier=null, endpoint=[localhost]:8085, alive=false, connectionType=MEMBER] closed. Reason: Connection closed by the other side
2021-09-20 15:35:11.092  INFO 11492 --- [ached.thread-13] c.h.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector      : [localhost]:8084 [dev] [4.0.2] Connecting to localhost/127.0.0.1:8085, timeout: 10000, bind-any: true
2021-09-20 15:35:13.126  INFO 11492 --- [ached.thread-13] c.h.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector      : [localhost]:8084 [dev] [4.0.2] Could not connect to: localhost/127.0.0.1:8085. Reason: SocketException[Connection refused: no further information to address localhost/127.0.0.1:8085]
2021-09-20 15:35:15.285  INFO 11492 --- [ached.thread-13] c.h.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector      : [localhost]:8084 [dev] [4.0.2] Connecting to localhost/127.0.0.1:8085, timeout: 10000, bind-any: true
2021-09-20 15:35:17.338  INFO 11492 --- [ached.thread-13] c.h.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector      : [localhost]:8084 [dev] [4.0.2] Could not connect to: localhost/127.0.0.1:8085. Reason: SocketException[Connection refused: no further information to address localhost/127.0.0.1:8085]
2021-09-20 15:35:17.450  INFO 11492 --- [cached.thread-3] c.h.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector      : [localhost]:8084 [dev] [4.0.2] Connecting to localhost/127.0.0.1:8085, timeout: 10000, bind-any: true
2021-09-20 15:35:19.474  INFO 11492 --- [cached.thread-3] c.h.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector      : [localhost]:8084 [dev] [4.0.2] Could not connect to: localhost/127.0.0.1:8085. Reason: SocketException[Connection refused: no further information to address localhost/127.0.0.1:8085]
2021-09-20 15:35:19.474  WARN 11492 --- [cached.thread-3] c.h.i.n.tcp.TcpIpConnectionErrorHandler  : [localhost]:8084 [dev] [4.0.2] Removing connection to endpoint [localhost]:8085 Cause => java.net.SocketException {Connection refused: no further information to address localhost/127.0.0.1:8085}, Error-Count: 5
2021-09-20 15:35:19.475  INFO 11492 --- [cached.thread-3] c.h.i.cluster.impl.MembershipManager     : [localhost]:8084 [dev] [4.0.2] Removing Member [localhost]:8085 - 2282b4e7-2b6d-4e5b-9ac8-dfac988ce39f
2021-09-20 15:35:19.477  INFO 11492 --- [cached.thread-3] c.h.internal.cluster.ClusterService      : [localhost]:8084 [dev] [4.0.2] 

Members {size:1, ver:3} [
    Member [localhost]:8084 - 4c874ad9-04d1-4857-8279-f3a47be3070b this
]

2021-09-20 15:35:19.478  INFO 11492 --- [cached.thread-7] c.h.t.TransactionManagerService          : [localhost]:8084 [dev] [4.0.2] Committing/rolling-back live transactions of [localhost]:8085, UUID: 2282b4e7-2b6d-4e5b-9ac8-dfac988ce39f
```

It seems that when I shut it down the second instance does not report that it is closing down correctly to the first one. We get a warning after it cannot connect to it for a couple of seconds and therefore removed from the cluster.

##### Second Instance (The one that was shutdown)

```
2021-09-20 15:42:03.516  INFO 4900 --- [.ShutdownThread] com.hazelcast.instance.impl.Node         : [localhost]:8085 [dev] [4.0.2] Running shutdown hook... Current state: ACTIVE
2021-09-20 15:42:03.520  INFO 4900 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.GracefulShutdown        : Commencing graceful shutdown. Waiting for active requests to complete
2021-09-20 15:42:03.901  INFO 4900 --- [tomcat-shutdown] o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.GracefulShutdown        : Graceful shutdown complete
```

It seams that it is trying to run a shutdown hook, but last report it does is still "ACTIVE" and it never goes to "SHUTTING_DOWN" or "SHUT_DOWN" as mentioned in this [artice](https://hazelcast.com/blog/rolling-upgrade-hazelcast-imdg-on-kubernetes/).

##### Config

pom.xml

```xml
...
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
...
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
            <artifactId>hazelcast-all</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
...
```

Just to add some context. I have the following application.yml

```yaml
---
server:
  shutdown: graceful
```

And the following hazelcast.yaml

```yaml
---
hazelcast:
  shutdown:
    policy: GRACEFUL
    shutdown.max.wait: 8
  network:
    port:
      auto-increment: true
      port-count: 20
      port: 8084
    join:
      multicast:
        enabled: false
      tcp-ip:
        enabled: true
        member-list:
          - localhost:8084
```

##### The question

So my theory is that Spring Boot shuts down hazelcast by terminating it instead of allowing it do shut down gracefully.

How can I make Spring Boot and Hazelcast shut down properly so that the other instances recognizees that it is shutting down rather then just be "gone"?

Comment: How do you create your Hazelcast instances ? If one is a Spring "@Bean", then Spring Boot will call the `shutdown()` method on it. But that would only shut down that one, hence leaving the other running. Check also https://hazelcast.com/blog/spring-boot-hazelcast-session-replication/ especially about the instance name property, it might be you don't need two Hazelcast instances.

Comment: @NeilStevenson, I do not create it myself. I let Spring handle the rest. The only config I have is literally the things I listed in the post. Exept I also have `@EnableCaching` in my App.java.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things at play here. First is a real issue terminating the instance instead of gracefully shutting down. The other is seeing it correctly in the logs.

Hazelcast by default registers a shutdown hook that terminates the instance on JVM exit.

You can disable the shutdown hook completely by setting this property:

```
-Dhazelcast.shutdownhook.enabled=false
```

Alternatively, you could change the policy to graceful shutdown

```
-Dhazelcast.shutdownhook.policy=GRACEFUL
```

but this would result in both spring boot gracefully shutting down = finishing serving requests and Hazelcast instance shutting down concurrently, leading to issues.

To see the logs correctly set the logging type to slf4j:

```
-Dhazelcast.logging.type=slf4j
```

Then you will see all the `info` logs from Hazelcast correctly and also changing the log level via

```
-Dlogging.level.com.hazelcast=TRACE
```

works.

Answer (score 0):

you get wrong way to config the property.
According [docs](https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/configuration/configuring-with-system-properties) your hazelcast.yaml should be like that:

```yaml
hazelcast:
  properties:
    hazelcast.shutdownhook.enabled: false
```

and then you can do something like that in spring

```java
    @PreDestroy
    public void shutDownHazelcast() {
        if (cacheParameters.isEnabled()) {
            log.info("Gracefully shutdown hazelcast");
            hazelcastInstance.shutdown();
        }
    }
```

you also can hazelcast standart hook with config (see ClusterProperty):

```
hazelcast.shutdownhook.enabled: true
#by default its TERMINATING!!!!
hazelcast.shutdownhook.policy: GRACEFUL
# seconds
hazelcast.graceful.shutdown.max.wait: 600
```